# Laravel Testing with Database - Single Transaction for every test not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit, laravel-7

I am using *Laravel 7.30.4*, *PHPUnit 8.5.14* and *MySQL 8.0.17*

So I have already written a few tests in the project I am working on and sometimes the tests failed with no good reason, or at least we weren't able to tell the problem (it happens like 1 in 200).
We then realised that the test which are writting to the DB are not resetting/rollbacking the data they wrote and this sometimes causes other tests to fail.
I have already tried a few things, none of them seem to work, for me

- [Resetting DB in Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) - did not do anything
- [Resetting DB after each test - Laravel 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) - causing errors
- [Resetting DB using transactions - Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#using-transactions) - also not working

My table engines are all set to `InnoDB`. I have also tried adding `protected $connectionsToTransact = ['mysql'];` to my tests when I used the old [Resetting DB using transactions - Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#using-transactions) method. Also I am using seeders in addition to my normal db migrations.

I have read many articles and some people say it's because MySQL does not support nested transactions ([here)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18429#issuecomment-288037091). Why does it work in the "normal" development and production system then?

Thanks for your help

Comment: transactions in the database - regardless if nested support or not - don't protect your database from changes, especially not on the database schema. what you're perhaps looking for is to create an (online) snapshot of the whole database before you start the test-suite-run and then just restore that snapshot point before you run the next time. consult your database administrator (dba) and your system administrator (sysadmin) what the best way to do this is for the database in question on the system in question. features in databases and in computer systems (e.g. filesystem) exist for that.

Comment: The schema is not getting changed. e.g. If a test inserts a row in the `customers` table, I want it to be gone after the test

Comment: You've mentioned _"Also I am using seeders in addition to my normal db migrations"_ and maybe I've misread about the db migrations that you also want to or implicitly put migrations under test and I associated that with potential schema changes. But regardless, this also applies to the data, given the system under test (SUT) uses db transactions, your database may not be capable to nest transactions and therefore they do not suffice _in testing_ for your purpose. Maybe this is what you experience?

Comment: But I am using the exact same database for testing as I use while developing and all the "normal" laravel transactions and rollbacks work there. 
The weird thing is, when I try to `DB::beginTransaction();` in my test, I get an error saying "laravel tests savepoint trans2 does not exist".

Comment: You use the same database, but you do more in the tests, especially more with the database. And unfortunately that causes the conflict, the tests are not transparent to the system under test. ;; The error message you see _""laravel tests savepoint trans2 does not exist""_ is Laravel trying to be helpful but could not succeed. If I understood it right, it's a workaround they do within transactions. I have no clue whether this is documented not only in the source code (it should be available to be studied) but also apart from it (which might help to get into the concepts).